# Why were the shevatim named by their mothers, not Yaakov

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, pentateuch-chumash, shevatim-12-tribes

Yitzchok and Yishmael were named by Avraham. Yaakov and Eisav were seemingly named by Yitzchok. Yet all of the Shevatim were named by their mothers, based on their situation at the time, without any clear input from Yaakov at all. Is there any reason given by the commentaries for this?

Comment: Levi and Binyamin?

Comment: The simple reading of the passuk by Levi seems to indicate that the name was from what Leah said. The drash is from a deviation from the other pesukim. In either case, it wasn’t Yaakov. Binyomin also was named by Rachel and Yaakov stepped in and changed it.

Comment: Rashbam and Radak both say Yaakov named Levi and that's a pretty plausible pshat

Comment: Rashi quoting the Medrash says it was Hashem

Comment: That's clearly less likely as pshat... Not sure why you're mentioning it. Anyway that's no worse than Yishmael and Yitzchak who were really named by God not Avraham

Comment: Note also Esav may have been named by Rivkah too

Comment: וַיִּקְרָ֨א אַבְרָ֧ם שֶׁם־בְּנ֛וֹ אֲשֶׁר־יָלְדָ֥ה הָגָ֖ר יִשְׁמָעֵֽאל׃. וַיִּקְרָ֨א אַבְרָהָ֜ם אֶֽת־שֶׁם־בְּנ֧וֹ הַנּֽוֹלַד־ל֛וֹ אֲשֶׁר־יָלְדָה־לּ֥וֹ שָׂרָ֖ה יִצְחָֽק׃

Comment: By Yitzchok it says a lashon zachor. וַיִּקְרָ֥א שְׁמ֖וֹ יַעֲקֹ֑ב. וַיִּקְרְא֥וּ שְׁמ֖וֹ עֵשָֽׂו. By all the Shevatim ( not Levi) it says lashon nekeiva.

Comment: וַיִּקְרְא֥וּ is not Zakhar. It's plural. And I can quote you the verses where God tells Avraham the name so not sure what you're trying to say with those quotes...

Comment: @double AA What I Am saying is that although Hashem told Avraham what to name him, in the end Avraham was the one who actually named him. By most of the Shevatim, it doesnot use plural nor Zachor, rather the mother named them without input from Yaakov. That is the question, why was Yaakov absent from the naming while Avraham and Yitzchok were present.

Comment: "the one who actually named him" I don't have a clue what that means. Your latter reformulation is much better since it avoids many of the problems we're discussing